# Azure App Service Backup Partial for Wordpress?

Tags: mysql, azure, backup, azure-web-app-service

App Service on Standard plan, using MySQL in-app database. App is stopped, and a manual backup always completes as "partial". The configuration for the backup blade shows no database exists. I am concerned that the database in the filesystem is not being included, so the restore will fail.

How can I be confident in Azure App Service Backup?

Thanks.

Added Information: Backup Log

```
CorrelationId: 19a70ee5-7158-49e9-8f58-35e39f231a34
Creating temp folder.
Retrieve site meta-data.
Backing up the databases.
Failed to backup in-app database. Skipping in-app database backup.
Backing up site content and uploading to the blob...
Uploading metadata to the blob.
```

Comment: Did you ever find out why this was happening or how to resolve it?

Answer (score -1):

Partially Succeeded means that there were likely some files which could not be backed up, because they were locked for some reason.  When this happens the backup process skips them and backs up the rest of the site and database if configured.  You should be able to see which files were skipped in the log file.  If for some reason you do not need these files backed up you can skip them by following the instructions in section “Backup just part of your app” [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-backup). 
[Stopping Locked On-Demand/Triggered Azure Webjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36684397/stopping-locked-on-demand-triggered-azure-webjob) sometimes is the reason for a Partially Succeeded backup status

Comment: Editing opening question. It is still not clear why the in-app database was not backed up even though the website was manually stopped and is not servicing requests. I need the complete backup!

Answer (score -2):

Using Azure website backup feature means you backup below things
1. Your web app configurations
2. Your actual web app file contents
3. The Azure MySQL database - This is optional. i.e. you can choose to back it up or not.
You can also try using using schedule backups. There is two options for this either schedule a full backup or partial backup using kudu console. 
You may refer to this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-backup

Comment: I reviewed the link, but it does not explain why my particular site is not getting completely backed up, which is what I want. "Partial" seems to mean that something is being missed by the backup management system, because I want the entire site to be captured.

Comment: Why am I getting a "partial backup" result, when the website is stopped and the DB is in the local filesystem? Your answer is not helpful. What am I missing? Thanks.